# How to pass dynamic data from page1 to page2 in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two pages in Jquery mobile(page1.html,page2.html,page1.js,page2.js). A form with dynamic list available in page1. I want to submit this form, then this form data pass to page2  and display in page2. 
 So how to pass the "page1" form data to "page2" using jquery mobile. Also page1 form contains dynamic list, so how to get dynamic list parameters in page2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `$.mobile.loadPage` will help you.

Although you have to use PHP.

```
$.mobile.loadPage( "page2.php", {
    type: "post",
    data: $("form#form_id").serialize();
});
```

And then in page2.php you should see the data

```
<?php
  print_r($_POST);
?>
```

If you can't use PHP then I believe you could use same script above, but use Js to extract GET parameters. Which I do not prefer.